# Is there an existing capability to allow editing of only pre-existing pages? If not, a good way to implement this?

Tags: user-access

I'm working on a setup for which I need general users to be able to edit a specific list of pages, but not create any new ones.

Looking through [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities), I don't see anything that will come close to this desired functionality, but I thought I might be looking through it.

Failing a pre-set, I started looking into [Advanced Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-access-manager/), but it was not immediately obvious to me if it would do what I need. Anyone with experience with this plugin have any idea where to begin?

Comment: I would also check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/

Comment: Also check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable posts, only allow to edit existing pages, not create new ones (create\_posts)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178033/disable-posts-only-allow-to-edit-existing-pages-not-create-new-ones-create-po)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress 3.5 there [will be a new capability](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16714) `create_posts`. You could create a new user role or change the role `editor` and [remove that capability](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16798/remove-capability-from-specific-user) for this role.

Comment: Fantastic! Just checked and it looks like I only have to wait a couple of days for this to come out!

Comment: You could also try the [Beta Tester](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-beta-tester/) plugin on a test installation and try it right now. :)

Comment: Awesome! I'll start digging into this when I'm back at work.