# Disable posts, only allow to edit existing pages, not create new ones (create_posts)

Tags: capabilities, permissions, user-roles

I am trying to limit a user role to only be able to edit existing pages, but not create new ones or do anything else like anything with posts.

I have read this:

[Is there an existing capability to allow editing of only pre-existing pages? If not, a good way to implement this?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74400/is-there-an-existing-capability-to-allow-editing-of-only-pre-existing-pages-if)
and the ticket mentioned there: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16714

So I created a new user role with those permissions:

- `edit_pages`
- `edit_others_pages`
- `edit_published_pages`
- `read`

Then I added this:

```
function disable_page_creation(){    
  if( check_user_role('rolename'){ // This checks if the current user belongs to this role
     get_post_type_object('page')->cap->create_posts = 'do_not_allow';
  }
}
```

The problem is that this not only disables creation of new pages but also makes anything else like listing pages forbidden.

As soon as I just add `edit_posts` everything is working as expected in the pages section, but of course posts are editable now.

Is this something WP just isn't capable of in this particular combination or am I just doing it wrong? Any hints where it gets stuck?

---

EDIT: Okay I think I am tracing down the issue. I believe the reason this happens is that posts and pages share the same admin file `edit.php`. Some more details:

The global `$pagenow` variable is set to `edit.php` no matter if we edit a post or a page.

In [user_can_access_admin_page()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L1689) this check is performed

```
 if ( isset( $_wp_menu_nopriv[$pagenow] ) ){
```

As the disabled post-editing puts `edit.php`in `$_wp_menu_nopriv[$pagenow]` it also bails out for pages.

I'd say this is a WP bug. Can anyone confirm or does have a solution?

Answer (score 10):

Okay here we go. It **is** [a bug in WordPress itself](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22895).

I have already shortly explained the issue in my question, so either have a look at it or check out the ticket linked above for more details.

Until the issue is properly resolved I propose this dirty, dirty hack. It is based off the idea that as soon as another sub-menu that is accessible is added everything is working fine again. So we temporarily add a dummy submenu-item just to trick the check and then remove it immediately.

```
function workaround_issue_22895(){    
        add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'Workaround_Issue_22895', 'Workaround_Issue_22895', 'edit_pages', 'workaround_issue_22895' );
        add_filter('add_menu_classes', 'workaround_issue_22895_unset');    
}

add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'workaround_issue_22895' );

function workaround_issue_22895_unset ($menu){
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'workaround_issue_22895');
    return $menu;
}
```

BTW, have I mentioned this is a dirty, dirty hack you should handle with care?