# Disable `create_post` for built-in post type

Tags: posts, user-roles, capabilities

I have some custom user roles for proofreaders which do not have the capability to create posts of my custom post types.

Unfortunately I am unable to find out how to remove that capability for the bulit-in `post` post type.

The Members plugin does not show the `create_post` argument, so I can't set it do deny (false).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to prevent them editing existing posts and deleting posts too?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook They should be able to edit them (correct errors), but they should not be able to delete them, yes!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There is no built-in capability of `create_post`.</strike>

**Update**: There is a capability `create_posts` but it's not well publicised and also has issues surrounding it which I'm afraid I don't have time to look into at the moment.

There are already answers that might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3248103

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/178059/94267

---

**Original answer:**

There is `publish_posts`.  You need to turn this off for those users.  Removing this capability doesn't prevent a user or role from writing a draft post, but it does prevent them from publishing it, so it won't be seen outside the admin.

Currently (WP 4.6) posts have these capabilities associated with them:

```
edit_posts
edit_others_posts
publish_posts
read_private_posts  
delete_posts
delete_private_posts
delete_published_posts
delete_others_posts
edit_private_posts
edit_published_posts
```

You probably want to disallow the `*_private_*` capabilities for anyone but Admins too.

Comment: Is there no possibility to add the `create_post` cap to the post type?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `create_post` cap.  If you've added your custom post type using a plugin, then that plugin may also manage a `create_thing` for the `thing` CPT, and you could write code to mirror that for the built-in post type.  Without knowing what it does in detail, I can't do that.

Comment: For my CPT's I have added the 'create_post' capability and set it to `create_CTP-name`. In the Members plugin `create_CTP-name` now shows up and it works like a charm. The only problem occurs with the built in `post` post type. My proofreaders should only be able to read and edit existing posts of any type, but not create new ones. Adding the `create_post` cap is really nice, because when set to false, the user does not have the "Add New" button.

Comment: It's a false sense of security though: They can edit an existing post to have whatever they like in it!  I'll see if I can dig up anything in my own code that will help.

Comment: I'm also talking rubbish - there is something about `create_post` that isn't in my own references.  I'll do a bit of searching for you and clarify my answer.

Comment: My initial idea was to even disallow them to save their changes. I wanted to have something like a "Submit for review", so that I have to check the changes and accept them. Unfortunately I also didn't find anything on that topic and here the forum nobody answered to my post.